# How can i create this table example with Primefaces p:dataTable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, foreach, datatable

I have a table in JSF Page:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" align="center">
  <col width="300"/>
  <col width="150"/>
  <col width="150" span="3"/>
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3" >&nbsp;</th>
    <th rowspan="3" >A</th>
    <th colspan="3" >B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">C</th>
    <th rowspan="2">D</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>E</th>
    <th>F</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>  
 <tbody> 

 <c:forEach items="${indexbean.regions}" var="r">
   <tr>
     <td colspan="5" >#{r.region}</td>
   </tr>

 <c:forEach items="${indexbean.table_data}" var="s">
  <c:if test="${s.reg eq r.region}"> 
  <tr>
    <td>#{s.rowname}</td>
    <td>#{s.d1}</td>
    <td>#{s.d2}</td>
    <td>#{s.d3}</td>
    <td>#{s.d4}</td>
  </tr>
  </c:if>    
 </c:forEach>

 </c:forEach>

 </tbody>  
</table>
```

These codes work properly. But i want to use primefaces p:dataExporter (for download this table as  Excel), that is why i must create this table with p:dataTable. I can't find solution what i can replace 2 forEach method in p:dataTable.
How can i create this table with Primefaces p:dataTable? Please, help me.